# Get client social signed in user on the server side

Tags: reactjs, azure-functions

I am using NextAuth to sign in users using Facebook or Twitter. This works fine and I get the AccessToken along with basic user info. On the server I am using the socialId of the logged in user to map to the corresponding local user in the database. Azure Functions has a social login feature called EasyAuth but I am not sure if I need it since I am using NextAuth. I was thinking of two ways:

1. Send the loggedin user object with every request? This is probably not save?
2. Send the access token with every request and the server calls the corresponding social api to get the user info again?

What would be a good practice security vice when sending the information to the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The client should not be aware of who is currently logged-in. On the client, you just save the access token, and then you send it to the server on every request. The server will figure out who made the request based on the access token and return the appropriate response.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. How would you send the access token to the server, should it be part of the authorization header parameter?

Comment: Yes, this is the most common way.

Comment: Ok thanks, in case of Twitter there is a access token and a token secret that is needed to access the api. Would it make sense to combine this into one string and send it in the authorization header and parse it on the server side?